# mysql error 1364 Field doesn't have a default values

Tags: mysql

My table looks like

```
create table try ( name varchar(8), CREATED_BY varchar(40) not null);
```

and then I have a trigger to auto populate the CREATED_BY field

```
create trigger autoPopulateAtInsert BEFORE INSERT on try for each row set new.CREATED_BY=user();
```

When I do an insert using

```
insert into try (name) values ('abc');
```

the entry is made in the table but I still get the error message

```
Field 'CREATED_BY' doesn't have a default value Error no 1364
```

Is there a way to suppress this error without making the field nullable AND without removing the triggfer? Otherwise my hibernate will see these exceptions ( even though the insertions have been made) and then application will crash.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Set a default value for `Created_By` (eg: empty `VARCHAR`) and the trigger will update the value anyways.

```
create table try ( 
     name varchar(8), 
     CREATED_BY varchar(40) DEFAULT '' not null
);
```

Comment: How to set a default value in a Java program?

Comment: you need a default value in the definition of the table (
    create table try ( name varchar(8), CREATED_BY varchar(40) DEFAULT '' not null) )

Comment: This does not address the root issue. See the much more extensive answer by Phyxx below.

Comment: @csvan Phyxx's answer does not address the root cause either because the root cause was a bug in MySQL that was fixed in v5.7.1 - see the answer by B98: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29854279/5389997  Removing strict_trans_table sql mode makes MySQL more prone to data quality errors, so removing it is not a really good advice.

Comment: @Shadow That explanation makes sense if you're developing an application, but the answer by @Phyxx is still useful and important for some users because many people use software packages developed by others (most that were designed for MySQL < 5.7) for `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` to be turned off (and more broadly, for the more permissive `SQL_MODE=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` rather than `STRICT`. This affects other things too, such as handling `DATETIME` columns; I've found both such errors tend to appear in many applications when migrating to MySQL >= 5.7.

Comment: @cazort those issues should be handled through the support for the 3rd party application, not as an answer on a programming Q/A site, which is aimed at developing new applications.

Comment: @Shadow There can also be reasons why a developer would want to use that solution, especially temporarily. I have done it myself when an application was designed for the lax settings, but I now control the code and it needs to go up in a short time-frame. Best practice is to know both solutions and apply them as needed. Applications are also common, where the data quality concerns are a non-issue, such as a web database where the overwhelming majority of use is read-only and only one admin ever edits the data.

Comment: @cazort if all these caveats would be escribed in that answer, I may even agree with you. These are not added, so the answer is outright dangerous.

Answer (score 233):

This is caused by the `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` SQL mode defined in the

> %PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini

file. Removing that setting and restarting MySQL should fix the problem.

See
[https://www.farbeyondcode.com/Solution-for-MariaDB-Field--xxx--doesn-t-have-a-default-value-5-2720.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20211019151342/https://www.farbeyondcode.com/Solution-for-MariaDB-Field--xxx--doesn-t-have-a-default-value-5-2720.html)

If editing that file doesn't fix the issue, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html for other possible locations of config files.

Comment: You can run an SQL query within your database management tool, such as phpMyAdmin:

`-- verified that the mode was previously set
select @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;

-- UPDATE MODE
SET @@global.sql_mode= 'YOUR_VALUE';`

Comment: but maybe you want STRICT_TRANS_TABLES  ?

Comment: in my case the field is of type DATETIME with default set as NULL, and I am still seeing the same error,
I have two schema on the same database. one for Staging, another for production, with the same table structures. 
It works in one schema, but does not work in another with exactly the same table structure in both. I am baffled.. I am not sure that it is an issue with STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

Comment: I removed STRICT_TRANS_TABLES from /etc/my.cnf -- in the line starting with sql_mode -- and restarted mysql service and issue went away.

Comment: The link to farbeyondcode is dead

Comment: I wonder if Stack Overflow will ever learn to provide a way to FIX the error, not to sweep it under the rug.

Answer (score 102):

Open phpmyadmin and goto 'More' Tab and select 'Variables' submenu.
Scroll down to find sql mode.
Edit sql mode and remove 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'
Save it.

Comment: This question is about MySQL, and doesn't make any mention of phpmyadmin. Please don't assume that everybody has that running.

Comment: @jackadams49 This change doesn't stick.  Can you advise me what you did to make this change survive a system reboot?

Comment: @jackadams49 to make it stay, `sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`, add `[mysqld]
sql_mode = "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"`, save and exit, and restart mysql  `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: To add, I had to change the values of `sql_mode` to null, ie `sql_mode = ""` for other similar errors.

Comment: We have recently upgraded our MySQL to 5.7. We were facing too many issues. This worked for me. Saved my day.

Comment: Thanks man. we upgraded to mariadb 10 from 5 and had this error popping up. saved my day +1

Answer (score 51):

In phpmyadmin, perform the following:

```
select @@GLOBAL.sql_mode
```

In my case, I get the following:

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES ,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Copy this result and remove `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`. Then perform the following:

```
set GLOBAL sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

Comment: ya but for that you will need to login to phpmyadmin with root account :) super account

Comment: after spending four hours, this solution worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04. Great !

Comment: you don't need `phpmyadmin` at all, use these commands on the `mysql` command line.

Comment: this will reset to default after mysql / server / pc restart. You need to edit /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf , and after [mysqld] add this line: sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_UBSTITUTION'

Comment: solution by @waza123, this one works for me after upgrading to mysql 5.7.20. thanks

Answer (score 32):

When I had this same problem with mysql5.6.20 installed with Homebrew, I solved it by going into my.cnf

```
nano /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.20_1/my.cnf
```

Find the line that looks like so:

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Comment above line out and restart mysql server

```
mysql.server restart
```

Error gone!

Answer (score 26):

Run mysql console:

```
mysql -u your_username -p
```

, select database:

```
USE your_database;
```

and run (also from mysql console):

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode='';
```

That will turn off strict mode and mysql won't complain any more.

To make things clear: your database definition says "this field must have default value defined", and by doing steps from above you say to MySql "neah, just ignore it". So if you just want to do some quick fix locally this solution is ok. But generally you should investigate in your database definition and check if field really needs default value and if so set it. And if default value is not needed this requirement should be removed to have clean situation.

Comment: Yeah don't add a default just remove the rules, great solution (sarcasm implied) never do this a great bad example. It solves the issue though

Comment: Yeah, agree with you. But sometime you got some other's people project, which is running well i.e. on production (where strict mode is not set) and you just want to add some small feature or bugfix, working local. You don't want to fight the dragons, just to make that da*n thing work. :)

Comment: for that scenario I agree

Comment: @zardilior what's the issue? default value is picked based on column type if the rule is removed.. I see nothing wrong about it :/ that rule is pretty harsh for no reason.

Comment: Not harsh at all, it just forces you to declare a default or provide a value, also strict mode works for way more things than only that, so disabling it, instead of declaring a deault on the column or passing the value, is really terrible mor ein prod. You disable one of mysql good charactersitics there

Comment: This worked perfectly, I just set the value of gzpost to NULL and the error went away :)

Comment: This solution is only temporary: it will not cause the change to persist after a server restart. To this end, you need to change the setting in the configuration file as the solution by @Phyxx recommends.

Comment: This is super awesome

Answer (score 17):

As others said, this is caused by the `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` SQL mode.

To check whether `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` mode is enabled:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

To disable strict mode:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode='';
```

Comment: Manually removed "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES" from variables > sql_mode for testing and it worked !

Comment: You saved my day.

Comment: For me after running the second command and checking sql_mode (1st command) it doesn't do anything. Even after restarting mysql service. Debian 9

Comment: Is there a way to apply this permanently, even after reboot?

Answer (score 15):

Before every insert action I added below line and solved my issue,

```
SET SQL_MODE = '';
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution,

```
SET SQL_MODE = ''; INSERT INTO  `mytable` (  `field1` ,  `field2`) VALUES ('value1',  'value2');
```

Comment: It is not needed to do that before every insert action, just do it one time at the beggining of your script, just after connect to the database, and every insert query will work without "Field doesn't have a default value" error.

Comment: This solution is fine because you don't need to alter tables (there may be a lot of fields to change).

Answer (score 14):

Modify your query and add "IGNORE" as:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO  `mytable` (  `field1` ,  `field2`) VALUES ('value1',  'value2');
```

Comment: this worked for me - my PHP script would abort, but with IGNORE, it just ads new row! Now, how "safe" is it to have IGNORE hardcoded into PHP-MYSQL query? I use this to auto-add rows, for new "day", where it did not exist before

Comment: @Levchik When you use IGNORE, then instead of an error, MySQL issues a warning when error happens, instead, and will try to complete the instruction somehow: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/

Comment: Worked like a charm! You saved my day~ Thanks a lot

Answer (score 12):

Its work and tested Copy to Config File: /etc/mysql/my.cnf OR /bin/mysql/my.ini

```
[mysqld]
port = 3306
sql-mode=""
```

then restart MySQL

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be caused by a **long-standing** (since 2004) [bug (#6295) in MySQL](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6295), titled

> *Triggers are not processed for NOT NULL columns*.

It was allegedly fixed in version [5.7.1 of MySQL (Changelog, last entry)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-1.html) in 2013, making MySQL behave as “per the SQL standard” (ibid).

Comment: I upgraded from 5.6 to 5.7.11 and the problem was fixed for me (and the removal of STRICT_TRANS_TABLES didn't work for me), so I'm upvoting this and downvoting the rest of answers

Comment: @knocte Not everyone can upgrade MySQL on his system, so it is not worth downvoting in favor of this.

Comment: The only answer that really help me. Removing `NOT NULL` constraint or adding default value to column fixed the problem. Trigger works as expected.

Answer (score 6):

For Windows **WampServer** users:

WAMP > MySQL > my.ini

search file for `sql-mode=""`

Uncomment it.

Comment: In my version I had to change: `sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"` to `sql-mode=""`. Uncommenting `sql-mode=""` caused the error.

Answer (score 4):

Most of these answers are a lot of work for the not-seasoned coder. Like mentioned the issues is with STRICT_TRANS_TABLES.

First verify `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` is running.

$ `mysql -u root -p -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';"`

You can disable strict mode on your MySQL server by running the following command on your Linode's command line:

$ `mysql -u root -p -e "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';"`

Then, you can verify that the mode is set by running the following:

$ `mysql -u root -p -e "SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;"`

This answer was found here https://www.linode.com/community/questions/17070/how-can-i-disable-mysql-strict-mode

Answer (score 3):

In Windows Server edit my.ini (for example program files\mysql\mysql server n.n\my.ini)

I would not simply set the sql-mode="", rather I suggest one removes STRICT_TRANS_TABLES from the line, leave everything as-was, and then restart MySQL from the services utility. Add a comment for future programmers who you are and what you did.

Comment: This answer tells the same. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52004654/10431118

Comment: Generally speaking yes, but my point is that I am saying specifically not to blank out all values of sql-mode, but rather to remove only STRICT_TRANS_TABLES only, as that's all you need.  Otherwise you could impact some other service.

Answer (score 2):

***This is for SYNOLOGY device users:***

---

- How to set global variables (strict mode OFF) on SYNOLOGY device.
  (checked on DSM 7.0.1-42218 - device model DS418)

Used PUTTY to connect:
login as **root** and
**sudo su** after... (to be admin total)

- if not exist create **my.cnf** in:

MariaDB 5:
/var/packages/MariaDB/etc
MariaDB 10:
/var/packages/MariaDB10/etc

- this should be in the file (at least for strict mode off)

```
# custom configs
[mysqld]
innodb_strict_mode = OFF
sql_mode = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

- restart mysqld daemon:
  MariaDB 5:
  /usr/syno/bin/synopkg restart MariaDB
  MariaDB 10:
  **/usr/syno/bin/synopkg restart MariaDB10**
- check for strict mode enabled at these two global options - both should be not there or off (see config above)
- log into mysql:
  **mysql -u root -p**
- enter password:

show variables like 'sql_mode';
show variables like '%STRICT%';

---

Answer (score 1):

i set the fields to not null and problem solved, it updates when an information is commanded to store in it, no more showing msqli message that the field was empty cus you didnt insert value to it, well application of this solution can work on some projects depends on your project structure.

Comment: It solved my error by altering column's `default` attribute from `none` to `NULL`. Unless of high rating answers! my cPanel was giving me access denied on shared hosting when I tried to update variable sql_mode.

Answer (score 0):

i solved problem changing my.ini file located in data folder. for mysql 5.6 my.ini file moved to data folder rather the bin or mysql installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think in name column have null values in this case.

```
update try set name='abc' where created_by='def';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Xampp 7.3.28-1 for Linux. It uses MariaDB 10.4.19. Its configuration file is:
/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf

It does NOT contain an entry that defines sql_mode.
However the query "select @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;" does return a result and it contains the problematic STRICT_TRANS_TABLES. I guess it is by default now.

My solution was to explicitly define the mode by adding this line below [mysqld]:
sql_mode=NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

You can define the modes that you need or just leave it blank.

Answer (score 0):

I found that once I removed what was a doubling up of a foreign key and primary key, when I could have just used the foreign key as the primary key alone in the table. All my code then worked and I was able to upload to db.

Answer (score 0):

in my case
Centos 8
Directadmin
Mariadb

Go to and edit:

```
- /etc/my.cnf
```

Add this text in last line - save file, and restart mysql

```
sql-mode=""
```

Final same as:

```
[mysqld]
...
sql-mode=""
```

Don't forget

```
/bin/systemctl restart mysqld.service
```