# PHP not inserting MySQL row when warnings are triggered

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have just inherited a `PHP/MySQL` application which I am providing support for. I have tried to set up my local environment as close to the production environment, however somehow, the live code is managing to insert a row of data where the **same code** on my local setup is producing a warning and not performing the insert.

I have tried turning off `MySQL Strict Mode` and running the query from `PHP` directly against the database, and I found that the warnings were generated but the insert still worked.

What is preventing the insert from happening from code within `PHP` in my local environment?

**UPDATE (Include Example)**

```
$sql="insert into table("name") values("12312341234")";     
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
    // do stuff
}
else {
    $error = mysql_error();
    data['error'] = $error;
}
```

The error message which is generated is

```
"Field 'filed_name' doesn't have a default value"
```

So basically, what is happening on the production server post query is a new row is appearing, however locally, there is nothing.

I will also mention, the `else` clause is not even present on the production code. I have put it there to simply find out what is going on.

Comment: Well for starters, showing us the error/code would help

Comment: Haha, yeah I know, however I am tied by an NDA which prevents me from displaying code. I will update my question with an 'example'. Sorry.

Comment: I understand. Btw, your query breaks as it is; Try this: `$sql="insert into table(`name`) values("12312341234")";`. I highly doubt thats the issue though.

Comment: Have a look if this helps : [mysql error 1364 Field doesn't have a default values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438840/mysql-error-1364-field-doesnt-have-a-default-values)

Comment: @Darren yes you are right, however the actual SQL which is executed becomes: insert into meetings(name) values('150414102616')

Comment: @Uours As I said, I have tried disabling String Mode. Adding a default value is not an option as it is a mediumtext type field. Also this whole application is going to be riddled with this kind of stuff (unfortunately) so I am hoping to be able to at least replicate the behaviour to start with before fixing things.

Comment: It looks like it is an issue with MySQL Strict Mode. However, simply changing this from within the database was not enough. I have provided an explanation of how I was able to replicate the behaviour below.

Answer (score 1):

The production enviroment may be configured to not show warnings with somethin like error_reporting(0); or similar configuration on php.ini. Maybe if you use this setup on your local enviroment the results will be similar. BUT. be aware: dont see the errors and/or warnings maybe a VERY dangerous thing. You should try to solve the problem that raise the warning.

Comment: Yeah I thought that too so I have already changed this, but it still is not inserting. I agree that it is better to solve the error than just not show it, I don't even know how this is possible. I have never seen code like this before!

Comment: hmmmm.. bizarre... well, you can also try using the @ at the line that raises the warning (which can be, again, a dangerous thing). You can also surround the problematic portion of the code with try-catch.... well, without seeing the code and without seeing the error message, it´s hard to help more

Answer (score 1):

> "Field 'filed_name' doesn't have a default value"

Meaning of the message is that

> You have a column in the table defined `not null` without a `default` value clause.
>      And unless which I can't insert without passing a value for it through an `insert` statement.

**Example**:

```
create table test_table( i int not null auto_increment primary key,
                         j int not null,
                         name varchar(10) );

insert into test_table(name) values( 'Ravinder' );
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'j' doesn't have a default value
```

Check for such field in your table and include it in your `insert` statement.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this. The field is of type mediumtext so does not actually allow for a default value. Apart from that, I am not actually trying to fix this error (just now). I am more concerned why the same code works on the production server but not in my local environment.

Comment: Check if there exist any before insert trigger on the table in pro server ?

Comment: There are no triggers.

Comment: And the column in pro server table has a `not null` on it or *not*?

Comment: Yes it does have not null set. I have no idea who would set a field not null and then write a query which does not set that value, however they have managed to make it work and I have no idea how!

Comment: Ok. Then it seems your current server environment's table does not match with that of pro server. Unless which, the query should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

So I have been able to replicate the behaviour. I had previously tried setting `sql_mode` from within the database.

```
SET @@global.sql_mode = '';
SET @@sql_mode = '';
```

This did not work. I am using `MySQL 64bit on Windows 7`. I tried editing the `my.ini` file and changing

```
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

to

```
sql-mode=
```

This prevented the **MySQL service** from starting.

In the end, I re ran the `MySQLInstanceConfig.exe` and unchecked the `Enable Strict Mode` option during the setup.

I also now think it might be possible to simply remove `sql-mode=` from the `my.ini` file all together to achieve the same result as this seems to be the only thing which is different after running the config wizard.

Lastly, I restarted `MySQL` and `Apache2.2`