# MySQL Foreign key not allowing insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue with a MySQL database I'm working on. I have a table `DAY_ITEM` with two nullable columns, `FOOD_ID` and `MEAL_ID`, that are foreign keys to the `ID` column in `FOOD_ITEM` and `MEAL_ITEM` tables respectively.

When I try to insert a new record into the `FOOD_ITEM` table I get this error:

```
[HY000][1364] Field 'FOOD_ID' doesn't have a default value
```

But that column isn't in the `FOOD_ITEM` table, the `FOOD_ITEM` table only has the `ID` column which is the foreign key of the `FOOD_ID` column in the `DAY_ITEM` table.

Below are my SQL scripts that make the tables, what I am doing wrong in these scripts?

**DAY_ITEM Script**

```
CREATE TABLE DAY_ITEM
(
  ID        BIGINT       NOT NULL,
  EMAIL     VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
  NAME      VARCHAR(100) NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  MOD_ID    SMALLINT     NOT NULL, #MOD = Meal Of Day
  MOD_NAME  VARCHAR(50)  NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  DAYS_DATE DATE         NOT NULL,
  FOOD_ID   BIGINT       NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  MEAL_ID   BIGINT       NULL     DEFAULT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE DAY_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT DAY_ITEM_PK_ID
PRIMARY KEY (ID);

ALTER TABLE DAY_ITEM
MODIFY COLUMN ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE DAY_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT DAY_ITEM_FK_EMAIL
FOREIGN KEY (EMAIL) REFERENCES USER_ACCOUNT (EMAIL);

ALTER TABLE DAY_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT DAY_ITEM_FK_FOOD_ID
FOREIGN KEY (FOOD_ID) REFERENCES FOOD_ITEM (ID);

ALTER TABLE DAY_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT DAY_ITEM_FK_MEAL_ID
FOREIGN KEY (MEAL_ID) REFERENCES MEAL_ITEM (ID);

ALTER TABLE DAY_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT MEAL_ITEM_UK_EMAIL_DAYSDATE_FOODID
UNIQUE (EMAIL, DAYS_DATE, MOD_ID, FOOD_ID);

ALTER TABLE DAY_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT MEAL_ITEM_UK_EMAIL_DAYSDATE_MEALID
UNIQUE (EMAIL, DAYS_DATE, MOD_ID, MEAL_ID);
```

**FOOD_ITEM Script**

```
CREATE TABLE FOOD_ITEM
(
  ID             BIGINT        NOT NULL,
  EMAIL          VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
  NAME           VARCHAR(100)  NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  SERVING_AMOUNT DECIMAL(6, 2) NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  SERVING_SIZE   VARCHAR(50)   NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  SERVING_ID     SMALLINT      NOT NULL,
  CALORIES       SMALLINT      NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  PROTEIN        SMALLINT      NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  CARBS          SMALLINT      NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  SUGAR          SMALLINT      NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  FIBER          SMALLINT      NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  FAT            SMALLINT      NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  SAT_FAT        SMALLINT      NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  MONO_FAT       SMALLINT      NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  POLY_FAT       SMALLINT      NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  TRANS_FAT      SMALLINT      NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  SODIUM         BIGINT        NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  CHOLESTEROL    BIGINT        NULL     DEFAULT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE FOOD_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT FOOD_ITEM_PK_ID
PRIMARY KEY (ID);

ALTER TABLE FOOD_ITEM
MODIFY COLUMN ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE FOOD_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT FOOD_ITEM_FK_EMAIL
FOREIGN KEY (EMAIL) REFERENCES USER_ACCOUNT (EMAIL);

ALTER TABLE FOOD_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT FOOD_ITEM_UK_EMAIL_NAME_SERVING
UNIQUE (EMAIL, NAME, SERVING_AMOUNT, SERVING_SIZE, SERVING_ID);
```

**EDIT**

Here is the insert statement I'm using that throws the error:

```
INSERT INTO FOOD_ITEM (EMAIL, NAME, SERVING_AMOUNT, SERVING_SIZE, SERVING_ID, CALORIES, PROTEIN, CARBS, FAT)
VALUES ('userOne@gravytrack.com', 'Caviar 2', 1.00, 'serving', 0, 250, 12, 13, 14);
```

I don't see why it's looking at the `FOOD_ID` in `DAY_ITEM` at all. I'm not inserting into `DAY_ITEM` I'm inserting into `FOOD_ITEM`. Even though I don't include an ID here it should just auto-increment. That's the way it worked in the past before I added the `DAY_ITEM` table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Field 'id' doesn't have a default value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865104/field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value)

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl Nope, wasn't the same problem at all. Did you read my actual question or just the title?

Answer (score 0):

insert a row with value NULL in id column in your parent table, then you can insert NULL value in child table.

Better option is you should avoid NULL values...

**Update:**

As you can see in your insert statement that food_id and meal_id fields are not included in insert statement means you are inserting default NULL value in these fields while in your master tables you have set these fields as not null means you are trying to insert a value (NULL) which does not exist in parent table.

Comment: To avoid null values would I need to use a linking table?

Comment: just set column property as not null or you can assign a default value.

Comment: I edited my question with the insert statement I'm using.

Comment: As you can see in your insert statement that food_id and meal_id fields are not included in insert statement means you are inserting default NULL value in these fields while in your master tables you have set these fields as not null means you are trying to insert a value (NULL) which does not exist in parent table.

Comment: Turns out the above scripts are just fine, and so is the insert statement. When I was setting up the hibernate entity classes with JPA annotations and adding the foreign key relationship I accidentally made hibernate add the `FOOD_ID` column to the `FOOD_ITEM` table. So there actually was a `FOOD_ID` column in the table without a default value. I deleted the column and everything works now. Just an FYI your solution would not have worked, just for future reference if you run into a similar problem.

Comment: Its good that your problem has been sorted out....but this error can occur only due to 2 reasons - either if trying to insert a row in child table which does not exist in master table OR strict mode is enable & column property is set to not null and we are not skipping that field in our insert statement....

Answer (score 0):

Try with removing `Default NULL` value and pass `NULL` while insert record.

your script shows like...

```
CREATE TABLE DAY_ITEM
(
  ID        BIGINT       NOT NULL,
  EMAIL     VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
  NAME      VARCHAR(100) NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  MOD_ID    SMALLINT     NOT NULL, #MOD = Meal Of Day
  MOD_NAME  VARCHAR(50)  NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  DAYS_DATE DATE         NOT NULL,
  FOOD_ID   BIGINT       NULL,
  MEAL_ID   BIGINT       NULL
);

ALTER TABLE DAY_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT DAY_ITEM_PK_ID
PRIMARY KEY (ID);

ALTER TABLE DAY_ITEM
MODIFY COLUMN ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE DAY_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT DAY_ITEM_FK_EMAIL
FOREIGN KEY (EMAIL) REFERENCES USER_ACCOUNT (EMAIL);

ALTER TABLE DAY_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT DAY_ITEM_FK_FOOD_ID
FOREIGN KEY (FOOD_ID) REFERENCES FOOD_ITEM (ID);

ALTER TABLE DAY_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT DAY_ITEM_FK_MEAL_ID
FOREIGN KEY (MEAL_ID) REFERENCES MEAL_ITEM (ID);

ALTER TABLE DAY_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT MEAL_ITEM_UK_EMAIL_DAYSDATE_FOODID
UNIQUE (EMAIL, DAYS_DATE, MOD_ID, FOOD_ID);

ALTER TABLE DAY_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT MEAL_ITEM_UK_EMAIL_DAYSDATE_MEALID
UNIQUE (EMAIL, DAYS_DATE, MOD_ID, MEAL_ID);
```

No need to change in second table.