# npoco.Insert<T> fails on table withOUT AutoIncrement Primary key

Tags: c#, mysql, orm, petapoco, npoco

I have an issue using the 'Insert of T' method of nPoco with a MySQL table defined like:

```
CREATE TABLE `TestTable` (
    `Id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `StatusEnum` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
)
```

Database.Entity defined as...

```
[TableName("operations.TestTable")]
[PrimaryKey("Id")]
[ExplicitColumns]
public class TestTable
{
    [Column]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public Status StatusEnum { get; set; } = Status.Default;
}
```

Code snippet:

```
// this works   
var foo = new TestTable { Id = 123 };
database.Execute(
    "insert into operations.TestTable (Id, StatusEnum) values (@0, @1)", 
    foo.Id, 
    foo.StatusEnum);

// this throws "Field 'Id' doesn't have a default value"
var foo2 = new TestTable { Id = 456 };
database.Insert<TestTable>(foo2);
```

Looking at the SQL generated by nPoco for the two inserts, I see this (from my log file)...

```
SQL: insert into operations.TestTable (Id, StatusEnum) values (?0, ?1) -> ?0 [Int32] = "123" -> ?1 [Int32] = "1"
SQL: INSERT INTO operations.TestTable (`StatusEnum`) VALUES (?0); SELECT @@IDENTITY AS NewID; -> ?0 [Int32] = "1"
```

For the 'Insert of T' method, why does nPoco think the Id column is an identity column?  Removing the 'PrimaryKey' attribute from the class definition doesn't help.

NOTE:  This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865104/field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value), but it might be slightly different.

Comment: Try changing your Primary Key definition to  [PrimaryKey("Id", AutoIncrement=false)]

Comment: That's it!  Add the solution and I'll mark it.  I'm not sure why I didn't think of that.  Though it does seem odd that default is 'true'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing your Primary Key definition to

```
[PrimaryKey("Id", AutoIncrement=false)]
```