# "Field doesn't have a default value" without strict mode

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column that is filled by a before insert trigger, this column is set to be **NOT NULL** and has no **DEFAULT VALUE**.

When I do a **INSERT TABLE** without passing this column, I receive the error: `1364 - Field 'column_name' doesn't have a default value`. I'd search the web for a solution and have encountered this question: [Field 'id' doesn't have a default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865104/field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value). I then checked and changed the mysql_mode from:

*"STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"*

to:

*"NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"*

but the insert query still returns the same error.

---

What should I do to bypass this "strict" mode? Or is it something else?
Please let me know if I need to include any config variable. I'm using mysql 5.6.39.

Comment: If it has no default value but must be set, then what value shall it have? Is there a proper reason for the column not to have a default value? It seems you want it to have one. (Otherwise include the value you want to insert in your insert statement in the trigger.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it's a calculated value and could not have a default value. It's currently been inserted by a before insert trigger, as I said on the question, but the error persists. :/

Comment: Ah, so your insert statement relies on the trigger to fill the column, but although the trigger is there to fill the column you still get the error. A bug probably. Or is the trigger not working as expected? Are you sure it fills the column in any case?

Comment: I've found this article from 2013: https://mysqlserverteam.com/before-triggers-and-not-null-columns-in-mysql/. This is actually a know bug, I'm going to try to update my mysql version.

Comment: See here for explanation and solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438840/mysql-error-1364-field-doesnt-have-a-default-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6295) for the mysql 5.6.39 version. And has been fixed since version 5.7.