# php artisan passport:install throws an error General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `oauth_clients`

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have this error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

```sql
insert into `oauth_clients` (
`user_id`, `name`, `secret`, `provider`, `redirect`, `personal_access_client`, `password_client`, `revoked`, `updated_at`, `created_at`
) 
values 
(
?, Laravel Personal Access Client, PH9RQTXPcpKZtaLl21NYiShxsBKtqB6ZCFgKlspz, ?, http://localhost, 1, 0, 0, 2021-12-18 18:35:17, 2021-12-18 18:35:17
)
```

why he throws this error? can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried changing mysql config : 'strict' => false. it is in database.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Field 'id' doesn't have a default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865104/field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value)

Comment: I found the issue , in my config file did not have passport.php file, i dont now why , but it is fact

Answer (score -1):

in my config file passport.php

1. `client_uuids=true`
2. `php artisan passport:install`
3. `client_uuids=false`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).