# MYSQL Database Error With mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, linux

What does this error mean and how would you fix this in general?

mysql exception 1364 (HY000): Field 'rawPassword' doesn't have a default value
here is source code which is where my error begins

```
        if self.auto_new_account:
            self.cur.execute(self.add_account, (username, self.get_hashed_password(password) , 0, 0 ))
            self.cnx.commit()

            response = {
              'success': True,
              'userId': username,
              'accountId': 0,
              'adminAccess': max(0, minAdminAccess)
            }

            callback(response)
            return response
```

Comment: Why is this tagged php and python? This is purely python code no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql error 1364 Field doesn't have a default values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438840/mysql-error-1364-field-doesnt-have-a-default-values)

Comment: this is what raw password was created like `rawPassword` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,