# Inserting specific query to the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, default-value

I'm trying to insert specific value to a MySQL table but whenever I do so, an error occurred and cant be inserted. As I traced it I noticed that the queries can only be inserted if all entities are given or all entities will be declared. How can I resolve this using PHP code?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $rec_qty=$_POST['rec_qty'];
    $id=$_POST['item_id'];

    for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['rec_qty']);$i++) {
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO itemlist (quantity) values('".$_POST['rec_qty'][$i]."') ") or die ("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn)); 

        $update = "$conn,UPDATE itemlist set quantity='$quantity' where item_id='$id'";

        if($sql) {
            header("Location: received_item.php?attempt=success");
        } else {        
            header("Location: received_item.php?attempt=empty");
        }
    }

/**Error description: Field 'item_name' doesn't have a default value**/
```

Comment: Can you post your SQL and log your errors for all to see?

Comment: Please add code, and error log

Comment: codes posted..thanks

Comment: Please add create table statement as column which is giving error is not in you code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438840/mysql-error-1364-field-doesnt-have-a-default-values , all explained here.

Comment: That update line looks wrong

Answer (score 2):

The `item_name` field in your table is declared as `not null` without a default value. One approach would be to supply it in your `insert` statement in the same way you provide the quantity.

Another approach would be to change the table's definition to either allow `null`s:

```
ALTER TABLE itemlist MODIFY COLUMN item_name VARCHAR(10) NULL;
```

or to have a default value:

```
ALTER TABLE itemlist ALTER item_name SET DEFAULT 'somename';
```

Comment: indeed it was declared as not null because there is a relationship between 2 tables. im trying to pass same field but only quantity will be alter.. for example im ordering 500doz and I only receive 450 so 450 will be the new value for my quantity.