# How to solve to ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO saveanswer (answer) VALUES ('d'). Field 'sanswer' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql

> ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO saveanswer (answer) VALUES ('d'). Field 'sanswer' doesn't have a default value

Comment: give default value null to sanswer column.

Comment: Providing the value for `sanswer` will solve your error. It is declared `not null` (it is probably your primary key) and not autoincrement, so you have to set the value (or use autoincrement or a default value).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql error 1364 Field doesn't have a default values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438840/mysql-error-1364-field-doesnt-have-a-default-values)

Answer (score 0):

One option will be to specify a value for that field in the query like this:

```
INSERT INTO saveanswer (answer, sanswer) VALUES ('d', 'something here')
```

Other solution will be to alter your table to set a default value for that field (null or something else) like this:

```
ALTER TABLE saveanswer ALTER COLUMN sanswer SET DEFAULT null;
```