# when i insert data its showing database error

Tags: php

When i was going to insert a student in my web app it was showing these error can anyone help me out.

> Error Number: 1364
>
> Field 'user_status' doesn't have a default value
>
> INSERT INTO `users` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `phone`, `profile_image`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `ip_address`, `created_on`, `last_login`, `active`) VALUES ('dinesh', 'kumar', '+919591812528', 'fa07b9fc131dc4c7caadac44539c81c4.JPG', 'dinesh kumar', '$2y$08$8KVwr6dQWp8GtsXcFPrRsujqFIBGwdu9MEgMniAXdznXQifCHuDe2', 'dineshprivacy007@gmail.com', '49.207.177.226', 1503992683, 1503992683, 1)
>
> Filename: /home/aspireng/aspiresms/models/ion_auth_model.php
>
> Line Number: 872

Comment: So what is unclear?

Comment: There's a field in your database called 'user_status' that is set to 'NOT NULL', and you don't have a default value for it. The poor database engine doesn't know what to do with the field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql error 1364 Field doesn't have a default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438840/mysql-error-1364-field-doesnt-have-a-default-values)

Answer (score 0):

`user_status` Column doesnt have a default value set, kindly set this field `NULL` as default, and then run query, or insert some value to this field.

Comment: hello sir,I changed the column value to null but again it was showing the same error

Comment: @DineshJack Please post your table structure, in your question

Answer (score 0):

if user_status field in your table, please set default value NULL if not assign.

Comment: hi bro, i was changed the user_status column as null now also it was giving the error. Can you please help me out

Comment: Please check your database engine and according set value of column

Answer (score 0):

This means there is a user_status column in you db which is expecting some value to be passed in. if you dont have any value to pass then do something like this

```
INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, phone, profile_image, username, password, email, ip_address, created_on, last_login, active,user_status) VALUES ('dinesh', 'kumar', '+919591812528', 'fa07b9fc131dc4c7caadac44539c81c4.JPG', 'dinesh kumar', '$2y$08$8KVwr6dQWp8GtsXcFPrRsujqFIBGwdu9MEgMniAXdznXQifCHuDe2', 'dineshprivacy007@gmail.com', '49.207.177.226', 1503992683, 1503992683, 1,'0')
```

your field user_status cannot be null so you need to pass any value in it. I just passed 0 for reference.