# How to insert data into MySql in some specific column in java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I'm having a problem.

I have a table called **issuebook** in my **MYsql database** where there are **5** columns.

The columns are: **memberid, membername, bookname, issuedate, returndate.**

So I only want to insert data in **3** columns in **memberid, membername, bookname** and leave the other 2 columns blank for now (because in those columns when admin gives date then data will be inserted in those columns).

But whenever I try to insert it, it shows me an error like this:

> java.sql.SQLException: Field 'issuedate' doesn't have a default value

My code is given below:

```java
String bname,name,id;
id = Start.ID1;
name = Start.NAME1;
bname = bookBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
try {
    pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into issuebook(memberid,membername,bookname)values(?,?,?)");
    pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id));
    pst.setString(2, name);
    pst.setString(3, bname);
    pst.executeUpdate();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Request is sent.");
    
}
catch (SQLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

My database table :

[image]

Comment: Probably `issuedate` column has been defined as 'not null'. Show us table definition.

Comment: @LukaszBlasiak
column name : issudate
Type              : date
Null               : Not null

Comment: @LukaszBlasiak I am not sure. I edit my question and uploaded a picture of my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `issuedate` column definition. As you have mentioned in comment - it is defined as *not null*.

Your SQL ommit `issuedate` column in `into` clause which means that query will try to insert `null` value into it. You have to provide date in your SQL or redefine `issuedate` column to allow null values.

Check out this SO thread [Field doesn't have a default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438840/mysql-error-1364-field-doesnt-have-a-default-values).

Comment: after editing my column defaultvalue from not null to null by your suggestioin it worked without any error. thanks a lot.

Comment: your're welcome, glad it helped :)

Comment: Thanks a lot once again :)